# How to show a different div on printing using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function printDiv() {

 var printContent1 = document.getElementById('divMail1');
 var printContent2 = document.getElementById('divMail2');

            var newWin = window.open('', 'PrintWindow', 'width=800,height=530,top=10,left=100,scrollbars=1,resizable=yes');
            newWin.document.open();
            newWin.document.write('<html/><body  onload="window.print()">' + printContent1.innerHTML + '</body></html>');
            newWin.document.close();
        }

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
  <div id="divMail1">
        <div>
            <img src="image1.jpg"/>
        </div>
     <div>
            <img src="image2.jpg"/>
        </div>


    <div id="divMail2">
        <div>
            <img src="image3.jpg"/>
        </div>
     <div>
            <img src="image4.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="printDiv()"/>
```

Hi, I want to show one div(divMail1) in print preview and print a different div(divMail2). is it possible. please help me.

Comment: You can't do that. Print preview shows exactly the page that's sent to the printer. (Unless by "print preview" you mean what's shown on the browser, then it's a different matter.)

Answer (score 2):

**Do it only with CSS**

```
<head>
        <style type="text/css">

        #printable { display: none; }

        @media print
        {
            #non-printable { display: none; }
            #printable { display: block; }
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="non-printable">
            Your normal page contents
        </div>

        <div id="printable">
            Printer version
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using JavaScript, you can use `print.css` by adding a `media="print"`. So, in your main CSS, you need to add this:

```
.print-only {display: none;}
.do-not-print {display: block;}
```

And in the `print.css`:

```
.print-only {display: block;}
.do-not-print {display: none;}
```

In your case, the code in your main CSS would be:

```css
#divMail1 {display: block;}
#divMail2 {display: none;}
```

And in the `print.css`:

```css
#divMail1 {display: none;}
#divMail2 {display: block;}
```

Comment: If there is a JDfiddle, it would be great. Sorry to be Dumb.

Answer (score 0):

use css instead

```
#divMail1 {
  display: block;
}

#divMail2 {
  display: none;
}
@media print {
  #divMail1 {
    display: none;
  }

  #divMail2 {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible without css?

Comment: for printer?... u can gen other page without unneeded elements and js just on button "print"